# I can not replace values on column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a column with values based on conditions (basically I am trying to create indexed classes in this column for multinomial logistic regression)

I tried using DataFrame.loc but I always get the same error

can any one can help me fix it ??

```
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] < 3), 'Freq_Rech'] = 1
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] >= 3) & (data['Freq_Rech'] < 6), 'Freq_Rech'] = 3
data.loc[data['Freq_Rech'] >= 6 & data['Freq_Rech'] < 10, 'Freq_Rech'] = 6
data.loc[data['Freq_Rech'] >= 10 & data['Freq_Rech'] < 20, 'Freq_Rech'] = 10
data.loc[data['Freq_Rech'] >= 20, 'Freq_Rech'] = 20
```

the error is:
    cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: you must have `()` parenthesis for each condition when using `&` multi conditions

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there. Just make sure to have correct sytax around your boolean conditions:

```
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] < 3), 'Freq_Rech'] = 1
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] >= 3) & (data['Freq_Rech'] < 6), 'Freq_Rech'] = 3
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] >= 6) & (data['Freq_Rech'] < 10), 'Freq_Rech'] = 6
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] >= 10) & (data['Freq_Rech'] < 20), 'Freq_Rech'] = 10
data.loc[(data['Freq_Rech'] >= 20), 'Freq_Rech'] = 20
```